# Calling 2 props onSLidingComplete in slider

Tags: javascript, react-native

**This is my card component. this card i want to call to main component**

```
const CardQuestions = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    return (
        <View style={styles.componentContainer}>

            <View style={styles.number}>
                <Text style={styles.h1}>{props.id}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                <View style={styles.questionContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.h1}>{props.title}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.titleSliderContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.h3}>Tidak Penting</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.h3}>Penting</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.slider}>
                        {/* Slider */}
                        <Slider
                            value={value}
                            step={1}
                            minimumValue={0}
                            maximumValue={100}
                            onValueChange={(val) => setValue(val)}
                            onSlidingComplete={() => props.getData(value),props.selectedId}
                            
                        />

                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.pointContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.inputPoint}>
                        <Text>{value}</Text>
                        {/* <TextInput

                            value={value}
                            onChangeText={val => setValue(0)}
                        // need handle ASYNCSTORAGE
                        /> */}
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setValue(0)}>
                        <Text style={styles.h2}>Clear</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

and this is my main component

```
<View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {

            const getData = (val) => {
              setHasil(val)
            }
            console.log(selectedId)
            return (
              <ScrollView style={styles.contentScoringContainer} >
                <CardQuestions getData={getData} id={item.id} title={item.title} value={item.value} selectedId={() => setSelectedId(item.id)} />
              </ScrollView>
            )
          }}
          extraData={selectedId} />
      </View>
```

**in here i want to call props.getData(value) and props.selectedId but just one of these can be use onSlidingComplete. If someone can help me, its so helpfull to me for finish my project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for.

```js
 <Slider
   value={value}
   step={1}
   minimumValue={0}
   maximumValue={100}
   onValueChange={(val) => setValue(val)}
   onSlidingComplete={() => {
     props.getData(value);
     props.selectedId();
     }
   }
 />
```